# Filter out (hide) Trello cards which have specific labels? (Negative Filtering)

Tags: trello

***Edit: To save anyone the trouble: As of late 2017 this is simply not possible. That's been confirmed to me by Trello support themselves.***

*Edit for clarity: I want to "hide", or "remove" specific cards using a filter. Currently you can only "show" cards. At the moment, each thing you select in a filter hides everything else and shows that thing. Select blue: you see only blue cards. Select also red: you see both blue and red cards. But I want to be able to say "Show blue but hide anything labelled red".*

I have a Trello board with cards which can be labelled "red" or "blue".

I want to be able to filter so that I can show cards which do not have the "red" label.

So I'd see:

Blue labelled cards.
Cards without a label.

But not:

Red labelled cards. 
Cards with both red and blue labels.

I know this can be done with a search but I want to filter. (Ideally in both the web app and the phone app - if it can be done!).

Is this possible?

Comment: This question was also later asked in Mar 2018 at https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Trello-questions/How-do-I-filter-to-exclude-a-label-Trello/qaq-p/748803 and has a response from a Trello team member.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan! Sadly it's the same answer: Can't be done. And still can't be done nearly four years later. Which is really strange as it doesn't seem like a very hard feature to implement either technically or from a UI perspective.

Answer (score 4):

As of late 2017 this is simply not possible. That's been confirmed to me by Trello support themselves.

Answer (score 0):

While it appears [at the time of this answer] negative filtering isn't possible, you can at least use the general search <kbd>/</kbd> to accomplish negative filtering.

For example, on Board *abc* if you'd like to filter out Label *xyz*: `board:abc -label:xyz`

Comment: Yes as I mentioned "I know this can be done with a search..." but I should have given an example. Thanks for adding that! But for my use-case this isn't useful at all, I want to see what's going on with one or two labels across a board without the noise that all the other labels introduce if they are visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a bit of a workaround which will give you a list of cards that DO NOT have certain labels.

Its using the trello Dashcards powerup to count the cards that meet the "not that label" criteria. and in doing so provides a list of all the cards that comply, which you can export to CSV for further examination.
https://trello.com/power-ups/6048e897c73d032a983e2a7c/dashcards

Its not a replacement for being able to filter the cards in place within the board, but at least gets you the card data you are looking for.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is 100% possible.

1. Click on *Show Menu* in the top right hand corner
2. Select *Filter Cards*
3. Click either the red label or the blue label and the other will disappear
4. You have visual indication that *Filtering is on* so you are aware not all cards are showing
   [image]

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't address my question at all. This simply shows how to filter on either Red or Blue, or both. That is just standard filtering. It does not show how to filter on Blue but NOT show Red. The point here is _negative_ filtering. And unfortunately I now know for sure that it's not currently possible to do this in Trello because I raised a ticket to Trello and got a Trello support person to confirm it. It's just not supported.

Comment: Sorry, I am missing something. When I filter by Blue, I do not see any card which are red unless they are also labelled blue, standard filtering like you say.

Comment: It's a little hard to be clear about in text: I am looking for negative filtering. I want to have a filter that says NOT red. So if I filter on blue, and there is a card with blue AND red <- that card would not show. Or if I don't do any other filtering at all, all red cards are hidden. I want to filter "out" cards by selecting a colour not just filter "in". Currently Trello only supports filtering "in" or positive filtering.

Comment: Or to put it another way: At the moment I can say "Show me only red" or "Show me red and blue". I cannot say "Hide all red".

Comment: I've edited the title and question to try to clarify it.